# Why won't my file print? I keep getting an I/O error

Tags: python

```
 print ('test.csv')

 # This is where all data will be place into CSV format
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as fp:
#csv = csv.DictWriter(fp, ['f1', 'f2'])
test_file = 'test.csv'
csvfile = 'test.csv'
csvfile = csv.DictReader(open (test_file, 'rb'), delimiter= ',', quotechar='"')
fieldnames = ['Somefield']
test_file = open ('test.csv','wb')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(test_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
csvwriter.writerow(dict ((fp, fp) for fp in fieldnames))
for row in test_file:
 csvwriter.writerow(row)
test_file.close()
for row in row: csv.writerow (row)
```

When I run this code I get IOError: File not open for reading at the "for row in test_file" what is the problem here? It seems to me like I opened it above.

Comment: Can you fix  your indentation please.

Comment: Try with  relative path

Comment: What Burhan said. Without proper indentation, it's impossible to tell the scope of the `with` block, which is crucial to the problem.

Comment: you use variables for different things, `test_file` is a string, then a file for writing; `for row in row` is nonsense; you open 'test.csv' as `fp` then as `test_file` then you use `fp` as variable for iterating over `fieldnames`. Use a variable only for **one** purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the begining of the file, you are opening `test.csv` in write mode. This will wipe out whatever was written there. <s>Also, you are opening it in binary format, but if it is a `csv`, you want to open it in text format.</s>

Other issues:

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as fp:
```

`fp` is not used anywhere else in the program. It is useless here, except for wiping the file clean.

```
csvfile = 'test.csv'
csvfile = csv.DictReader(open (test_file, 'rb'), delimiter= ',', quotechar='"')
```

The first line does nothing, as it will just be overwritten. Again, you are opening the empty file.

```
test_file = open ('test.csv','wb')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(test_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

And here you are, opening the same file again.

```
for row in row:
    csv.writerow (row)
```

What do you want to do here? You are overwriting your iterator in a very confusing manner. Perhaps you want to do something like `for row in test_file`.

Also, writerow is a method of `DictWriter`, not of csv. This will raise an exception.

Comment: CSV files should be opened in binary format in Python 2 (which the OP may not be using, judging from the `print()` call in his code) in order to not modify fields with embedded line breaks. In Python 3, the `newline=''` parameter should be used.

Comment: i modified the code to meet what you said. Now I'm getting 

csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(test_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)

 in __init__
    self.writer = writer(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Comment: what is `test_file`? It has to be an open file. You should consider reading the documentations examples for clarification: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You have opened the same file twice on different file handles. This will not work.  Use a different file name for output, or read and close and reopen before writing.